# Extjs refer to parent window from new window

Tags: javascript, extjs

Using Extjs 5.0.1 I have a `Ext.toolbar.Toolbar` with a button. When I click in the button a new window is opened with a form inside. Inside the form I need to refer about the toolbar, but using `form.up('toolbar')` don't work and it return `undefined`. It seems becouse the new window is not bind with the toolbar. I don't want to use `getCmp` becouse I am not using the `id` property.

Have you any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  `Ext.ComponentQuery.query` to find the toolbar.

Using xtype `toolbar`,it will return an array of objects.

```
 Ext.ComponentQuery.query('toolbar')[0];
```

If you have more than on toolbars,you can give a unique itemId to the toolbar  in config like `itemId:'buttonToolbar'`.

```
 Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#buttonToolbar')[0];
```

Similarly you give a unique name to the toolbar in config like `name:'buttonToolbar'`.

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('toolbar[name=buttonToolbar]')[0];
```

Comment: I am not using xtype.. can I use Ext.ComponentQuery.query('toolbar')[0]; ?

Comment: yes why not, but make sure you have only one toolbar in your view

Answer (score 0):

```
onBtnABCClick:function(btn) {
    Ext.create('MyApp.view.NewWindow',{
        myParentToolbar: btn.up('toolbar') // <- here you give your new window a config item
    });
}


onWindowAfterRender:function(component) {
    // here you can access the new config item:
    component.config.myParentToolbar.down('button[itemId=ABC]').setDisabled(true);
    // in ExtJS 4, it was "component.myParentToolbar", in ST2 "component.config.myParentToolbar".
    // Unsure about ExtJS 5, please test both possibilities.
}
```